# OpenCV::dnn::readNet throwing exception

Tags: c++, opencv, onnx

I am following [this tutorial](https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/) to load the `yolov5*.onnx` models with the OpenCV DNN module and use it to make inference. I get the following error when trying to load the model:

> [ERROR:0@10.376] global E:\Libraries\C++\opencv_gpu\opencv_source\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp (1021) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 1 inputs and 1 outputs: [Identity]:(onnx_node!Identity_0) from domain='ai.onnx' OpenCV(4.6.0-dev)
>
> E:\Libraries\C++\opencv_gpu\opencv_source\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:1040: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::handleNode' > Node [Identity@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!Identity_0) parse error: OpenCV(4.6.0-dev) E:\Libraries\C++\opencv_gpu\opencv_source\modules\dnn\src\layer.cpp:246: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Layer::getMemoryShapes' >

The minimal code to reproduce the error is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// openCV related includes
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
using namespace cuda;

int main()
{
    printCudaDeviceInfo(0);
    
    // Load model.
    Net net;
    try
    {
        //net = readNet("yolov5s.onnx");
        net = readNetFromONNX("yolov5s.onnx");
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << endl << endl << e.msg << endl << endl; // output exception message
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0
}
```

I built OpenCV from source with CUDA / CuDNN other relevant modules using cmake on windows. (OpenCV version 4.6.0).

Why I am getting this exception? How can I correctly load the `onnx` model of `yolo`?

Comment: For reference, this is the relevant source throwing the error: [layer.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/dnn/src/layer.cpp)

Comment: Some [suggest](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/8439) downgrading PyTorch to v1.11 before exporting to ONNX. I can also confirm that using PyTorch 1.8.2 LTS produces a model which OpenCV v4.6.0 can read.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no experience using any of the listed technologies except for C++.

The last line of the error message you are seeing

> ```
> E:\Libraries\C++\opencv_gpu\opencv_source\modules\dnn\src\layer.cpp:246: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Layer::getMemoryShapes' >
> ```

failed an assertion that `inputs.size()` is non-zero. I think it may be due to you not setting inputs for your `Net` object. In the tutorial which you linked to, in section 4.3.4, they implement a helper function "`pre_process`", which takes an input image, converts it to a blob, and sets that as the input of the net. See section 4.3.6 for how/where they call `pre_process` in their `main` function. Are you following that part of the tutorial outside of the minimal reproducible example you provided?

I don't know anything about ONNX, so if your input is being set inside your ONNX file, please add the body of the file to your minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I used your good minimal example and reproduced the error with opencv 4.6.0 (build from source):

```
[ERROR:0] global ../modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp (1876) handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 1 inputs and 1 outputs: [Identity]:(onnx::Reshape_475)
```

I seems to be a version problem of either:

1. opencv reading the onnx file
   (I was able to read an other onnx e.g. the restnet onnx file [here](https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/main/vision/classification/resnet/model/resnet18-v1-7.onnx) without any trouble)
2. the pip package of [onnx v.1.12](https://pypi.org/project/onnx/1.12.0/)  is producing an file version (called for onnx 'opset version') which could not yet be handled by opencv

I haven't found the right combination ( and I tried some), but some people in the comment section of your mentioned article suggested to use opencv version [4.5.4.60](https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/#disqus_thread)

An alternative A) is to use an other format like TensorFlow GraphDef *.pb files
The funtion  [cv::dnn::readNet](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga3b34fe7a29494a6a4295c169a7d32422) suggests a lot more options:

```
*.caffemodel (Caffe, http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/)
*.pb (TensorFlow, https://www.tensorflow.org/)
*.t7 | *.net (Torch, http://torch.ch/)
*.weights (Darknet, https://pjreddie.com/darknet/)
*.bin (DLDT, https://software.intel.com/openvino-toolkit)
*.onnx (ONNX, https://onnx.ai/)
```

The [export.py](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/export.py) script of the project yolov5 offers some options:
Format                      | `export.py --include`         | Model
---                         | ---                           | ---
PyTorch                     | -                             | yolov5s.pt
TorchScript                 | `torchscript`                 | yolov5s.torchscript
ONNX                        | `onnx`                        | yolov5s.onnx
OpenVINO                    | `openvino`                    | yolov5s_openvino_model/
TensorRT                    | `engine`                      | yolov5s.engine
CoreML                      | `coreml`                      | yolov5s.mlmodel
TensorFlow SavedModel       | `saved_model`                 | yolov5s_saved_model/
TensorFlow GraphDef         | `pb`                          | yolov5s.pb
TensorFlow Lite             | `tflite`                      | yolov5s.tflite
TensorFlow Edge TPU         | `edgetpu`                     | yolov5s_edgetpu.tflite
TensorFlow.js               | `tfjs`                        | yolov5s_web_model/

An alternative B) could be to use the pip package onnx to convert the file version. See the [docu here](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/VersionConverter.md).