# yolov7 Object Detector

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, yolov5

I used yolov5 for my object detection. Now I am trying to improve it to YoloV7. I trained my dataset and convert it from .pt to .onnx. But I cannot implement it to my code. I shared the code in the below. I got that error:

```
v2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:928: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'handleNode'
> Node [NonMaxSuppression@ai.onnx]:(onnx::Gather_626) parse error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:621: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "onnx::Gather_626" of type "NonMaxSuppression" in function 'getLayerInstance'
```

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import webcolors
import time
import requests 
start = time.time()

path = "/Users/admin/Desktop/ML/"


productsArray = []
products = []
classNames = []
allProductsArray = []



def format_yolov5(frame):

    row, col, _ = frame.shape
    _max = max(col, row)
    result = np.zeros((_max, _max, 3), np.uint8)
    result[0:row, 0:col] = frame
    return result
    
# Loading image
image = cv2.imread(path+"Images/2.jpg")
img = format_yolov5(image) # making the image square


#######DETECTION###########

def Detect():
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(path+"Config/data.onnx")
    
# Detecting objects
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img , 1/255.0, (640, 640), swapRB=True)
    net.setInput(blob)
    predictions = net.forward()

    class_list = []
    with open(path+"Config/obj.names", "r") as f:
        class_list = [cname.strip() for cname in f.readlines()]
    

# Showing informations on the screen
    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []

    output_data = predictions[0]
    image_width, image_height, _ = img.shape
    x_factor = image_width / 640
    y_factor =  image_height / 640

    for r in range(25200):
        row = output_data[r]
        confidence = row[4]

        if confidence >= 0.55:
            classes_scores = row[5:]
            _, _, _, max_indx = cv2.minMaxLoc(classes_scores)
            class_id = max_indx[1]
            
            if (classes_scores[class_id] > .25):
                confidences.append(confidence)

                class_ids.append(class_id)

                x, y, w, h = row[0].item(), row[1].item(), row[2].item(), row[3].item() 
                left = int((x - 0.5 * w) * x_factor)
                top = int((y - 0.5 * h) * y_factor)
                width = int(w * x_factor)
                height = int(h * y_factor)
                box = np.array([left, top, width, height])
                boxes.append(box)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.3, 0.4) 

    result_class_ids = []
    result_confidences = []
    result_boxes = []
    
    for i in indexes:
        result_confidences.append(confidences[i])
        result_class_ids.append(class_ids[i])
        result_boxes.append(boxes[i])

                
    for i in range(len(result_class_ids)):

        box = result_boxes[i]
        class_id = result_class_ids[i]
        label =(class_list[class_id])
        allProductsArray.append(label)
        cv2.rectangle(img, box, (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (box[0], box[1] - 20), (box[0] + box[2], box[1]), (0, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(img, class_list[class_id], (box[0], box[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0,0,0))
        cv2.putText(img, str(result_confidences[i]), (box[0]+60, box[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .6, (0,0,0))



Detect()

print(allProductsArray)
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me. If you want to share code please post a minimal reproducible example as text with code markups. [ask]

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: My comment might be irrelevant to your problem because the error looks a bit different, but there are known issues when converting PyTorch models to ONNX and then reading them with OpenCV, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73195979/opencvdnnreadnet-throwing-exception) and [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/8439). A workaround might be to downgrade PyTorch before conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand well what you want to do (Run Yolov7 inference or Yolov5) but I hope this repo could help:

https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/ONNX-YOLOv7-Object-Detection